# Build Server Hangs : Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Tags: slf4j, logback

I am using SLF4J (1.6.1) + logback (1.1.2) in my project. while taking build I have noticed that after getting "Registering current configuration as safe fallback point" this log my build server couldn't continue. what is the issue and how to fix this one.

Comment: I have faced the same problem, when I debugged I found that there was a formatting issue in my application.yml, due to which it was hanged and there was not proper error message.

Comment: In my case it was exactly what chandramohan , a duplicated key on the yml

Comment: in my case it was due to update of google map library version. i reduced the library version, then it started working